# Split up the data from ck editor

Tags: php, database, ckeditor

I am using ck editor to save some particular data including a image and some text.What i am trying to achieve is to split up the image and the text that i am entering in the ck editor and save it in database.i have done it so far as in the image below.Saved in database.But didn't split up the image and text.Is there any posiible way guys.

[image]

Now both the image and text is saving under the field `content` in database. I need to save the image in one field, and text(test as you can see in image) in other field

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate inputs. One for image and one for description.

```
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<textarea name="content"></textarea>
```

---

If you wish to extract image from text, then when showing content you have to parse it again

Answer (score 0):

Parse html befor inserting ck editor data into the database or after. And you will get structured data about  img tag and src attribute value for processing.